# Adding minutes to datetime on insert - mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I've tried this

```
INSERT INTO products 
 (product_id, product_type, created_dt, end_dt) 
VALUES 
 ('11', '1', '2010-10-08 00:11:10', DATE_SUB(2010-10-08 00:11:10, INTERVAL 59 Minute))
```

But this doesn't work.  Any other ways to do this within Mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO products 
  (product_id, product_type, created_dt, end_dt) 
VALUES 
  (11, 
   '1', 
   '2010-10-08 00:11:10', 
    DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2010-10-08 00:11:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 59 MINUTE)
  )
```

On MySQL 5.1.49, it wouldn't add/subtract because it wasn't implicitly converting the string to a DATETIME data type.  So I had to [use STR_TO_DATE to explicitly convert the string into a DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  Otherwise, MySQL workbench returns `BLOB`...

Comment: @dave: You're welcome - I wouldn't have caught the issue if I wasn't testing it.

Comment: Actually, this seemed to have subtracted 59 seconds instead of added

Comment: @dave: Corrected - I wondered why the title said "add", but your example was subtraction.

Comment: Duh, hence the DATE_SUB - I've changed it to DATE_ADD

Answer (score 0):

Use `timestamp` for your database..
like

```
$date = time();
```

and save this variable as a value in your database.

If you want to retrieve a date in date format then use this time stamp in

```
time('M-Y-D',timestamp);
```

it will format the timestampin date format or format u put in the function...

check PHP mannual for `time()` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO products 
 (product_id, product_type, created_dt, end_dt) 
VALUES 
 ('11', '1', '2010-10-08 00:11:10', '2010-10-08 00:11:10' - INTERVAL 59 Minute)
```

Comment: `'2010-10-08 00:11:10' - INTERVAL 59 Minute` returns `BLOB` in MySQL Workbench, against MySQL 5.1.49